# My Phanpy won't breed with my Sneasel

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I got a male Sneasel, and I'm trying to it breed with a Phanpy, to share ice shards with it. However, they won't breed! I looked up the breeding charts, and the wiki says that they are compatible. So why won't they breed?

Comment: Just to clarify: is your Phanpy female?

Answer (score 2):

Phanpy and Sneasel are compatible, they are both in the `Field Egg Group`, and so can breed if the right requirements are met.

## Breeding

```
|-----------|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
|  Species  |  Original |                                 Quote                                  |  Egg Chance  |
|           |  Trainer  |                                                                        | (Oval Charm) |
|-----------|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
|   Same    | Different | "The two seem to get along very well!"                                 | 70% (88%)    |
|   Same    |   Same    | "The two seem to get along."                                           | 50% (80%)    |
| Different | Different | "The two seem to get along."                                           | 50% (80%)    |
| Different |   Same    | "The two don't really seem to like each other very much."              | 20% (40%)    |
|-----------|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
| Different Egg Groups, |                                                                        |              |
| same Gender,          | "The two prefer to play with other Pokémon more than with each other." |  0% ( 0%)    |
| or Undiscovered Group |                                                                        |              |
|-----------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
```

As you can see, from the table, your Pokémon must not be the same `Gender` if they want to breed. If they are, then you must catch one of a different `Gender`.

As well as that, there isn't a 100% chance you'll get an egg; obtaining an `Oval Charm` helps to increase your chance of receiving an egg.

See what message the Day Care Man gives you when you talk to him, to determine what is wrong with the two Pokémon you give him. (This is different in [ORAS](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/ORAS) and in Generation II)

For more information, see the wiki:

- [Breeding](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Breeding)
- [Egg Groups](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Egg_Group)

Comment: The [Oval Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolution-inducing_held_item#Oval_Stone) has no effect on breeding, and is only used to evolve Happiny. Were you perhaps thinking of the [Oval Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oval_Charm) key item?